# Find running sum of a row column wise and show it in another row in same dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help in calculating running SUM of a row column wise and show it in another row of the same dataset.

I have a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(ObservationDate VARCHAR(100),
IOLinetype      VARCHAR(100),
PatInfoID       VARCHAR(100),
LineTypeName    VARCHAR(100),
LineName        VARCHAR(100),
LineNameString  VARCHAR(100),
LineType        VARCHAR(100),
[00:00]         INT,
[01:00]         INT,
[02:00]         INT,
[03:00]         INT,
[04:00]         INT
);
```

With data like so:

```
INSERT INTO #tempTable VALUES
('2017-10-25','INPUT','839','Hourly Input', 'Hourly Input', 'Hourly Input','5.5', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
('2017-10-25','OUTPUT','839','Hourly Output', 'Hourly Output', 'Hourly Output','5.5', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
('2017-10-26','INPUT','839','Hourly Input', 'Hourly Input', 'Hourly Input','5.5', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
('2017-10-26','OUTPUT','839','Hourly Output', 'Hourly Output', 'Hourly Output','5.5', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

[image]

And I want result like so:
[image]

Help in this regard will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is there any identity id or more accurate date in order to sort the rows in the way they are inserted?

Comment: Also, calculations are not clear. How you get `10` and `15`?

Comment: @gotqn: I have got this dataset after heavy manipulation. Cant we use rownumber to add unique value to each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select ObservationDate, IOLinetype, PatInfoID, LineTypeName, LineName, LineNameString, LineType,
       [00:00], [01:00], [02:00], [03:00], [04:00] 
from #tempTable
union all
select ObservationDate, 'TOTAL INPUT', PatInfoID, 'Total Input', 'Total Input', 'Total Input', '5.6',
       [00:00], [00:00] + [01:00], [00:00] + [01:00] + [02:00],
       [00:00] + [01:00] + [02:00] + [03:00], 
       [00:00] + [01:00] + [02:00] + [03:00] + [04:00] ;
```

Your original data does not have an obvious ordering.  If it did, you could order by that.  For instance, if the `ObservationDate` had a time component:

```
order by ObservationDate, LineType
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) to rotate columns into column values, calculate a running total using `SUM()` (see [How to Find Running Total in SQL Server](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/10/04/sql-server-how-to-find-running-total-in-sql-server/) blog), and then use PIVOT to rotate the results back into column values.

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM (

    -- Original table
    SELECT ObservationDate, IOLinetype, PatInfoID, LineTypeName, LineName, LineNameString, LineType
           ,[00:00], [01:00], [02:00], [03:00], [04:00]
    FROM #tempTable

    UNION ALL

    -- Pivoted Running total
    SELECT   pvt.ObservationDate
            ,'TOTAL ' + pvt.IOLinetype
            ,PatInfoID, LineTypeName, LineName, LineNameString, LineType
            ,[00:00], [01:00], [02:00], [03:00], [04:00]
    FROM (
        -- Unpivoted data with a Running total
        SELECT   ObservationDate, IOLinetype, PatInfoID, LineTypeName, LineName, LineNameString, LineType, Time
                ,SUM(unpvt.[Value]) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY unpvt.ObservationDate ,unpvt.IOLinetype
                        ORDER BY unpvt.ObservationDate
                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
                    AS Value_Total
        FROM #tempTable t
        UNPIVOT (
            [Value] FOR [Time] IN ([00:00], [01:00], [02:00], [03:00], [04:00])
        ) unpvt
    ) rt
    PIVOT (
        SUM(Value_Total)
        FOR [Time]  IN ([00:00], [01:00], [02:00], [03:00], [04:00])
    ) pvt
) t

-- Sort everything
ORDER BY 1, LineTypeName, CASE WHEN IOLinetype LIKE 'TOTAL%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC
;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i strongly recommend to change the structure of this table. Data about hourly input should be keeped in different table.
To achieve this in your way, i would probably try unpivot the table (with UNPIVOT operator or cross apply) and then try to sum values in groups.